# configure git on two levels: local + dev server + prd server

Tags: git

I have a local machine where I develop my project with git configured and I push the commits to the production environment with `git push live` where live is the remote server.

Now I want to put an intermediate level to be able to have someone else contributing so I want to have: my local machine and other developers ones to push their commit to the dev server.

Then on the dev server git configured to push the commits to the production server. My question is: to setup the push between local and production currently I have

```
git remote add live ssh://user@server1.example.com/home/user/mywebsite.git
```

but I need to have the possibility to review the changes in dev, commit them on the dev server and then push them to the prod.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this:

1. create your `dev` branch from `live` branch.
2. from now on developers will work on `dev` branch, create a new branch from `dev`, push and then create merge request from that new branch to `dev`.
3. at anytime, you can check commits and test on your dev server with code on `dev` branch.
4. when you want to deploy to `live` you have 2 options:

- just create a merge request from `dev` to `live`. you can review changes in this merge request. but it will includes merge commits from dev
- create a `release` branch from `live`. cherry-pick all the commit you want from `dev` to that new `release` branch, and then merge `release` branch to `live`, this way will give you a "cleaner" `live` branch.

Comment: I would like to have a three level structure: first level each developer that will push to the second level a test site (where tester will make their work) and third level the production environment. I'll surely use branches but in your approach you consider just two levels

Comment: i will call your test level = stagging. So you can create 1 more `stagging` branch from `live`.
then, the dev site pull code from `dev`, staging site pull code from `staging` and production site from `live`.
you can use my approach, with `dev` and `staging` branch when you want to deploy staging site you only need to merge all commit from `dev` to `staging`. when you want to deploy to production, use cherry-pick approach with `staging` and `live`. so you will have whatever on `dev` and `staging` but only what you really want to deploy on `live`.

Comment: And you can fix bug on `dev` and do testing on `staging` before merge it to `live` too.

Comment: you talk about branches but i talk about different machines/servers with different addresses

Comment: as i understand, you can use each branch to deploy on your 1 server/machine, for example, on your developing machine, you can pull code from `dev` only, on test server you pull from `staging` and from live/product machine you pull from `live` branch only